# Visual Basic LinQ to XML cannot select objects

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a C# code like this

```
var books = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(_filename).Root.Elements("Book").Select(
            x => new Book(
                (string)x.Element("Title"),
                (string)x.Element("Author"),
                (string)x.Element("Publisher"),
                (string)x.Element("ISBN")));

return books;
```

I converted it to VB but i dont know how can i write the selection part.

```
Dim books = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(_filename).Root.Elements("Book").
            Select( /****what should i write here  ***/ ) 
Return books
```

Comment: You need to use `DirectCast` to cast the element to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another important point is that you are probably looking for `XElement.Value`:

```
x.Element("Title").Value
```

Rather than

```
x.Element("Title")
```

Because the first one would return

```
"My Book"
```

And the second one - something like:

```
"<Title>My Book</Title>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
.Select(Function (x) 
    Return new Book(
     CType(x.Element("Title"), String),
     CType(x.Element("Author"), String),
     CType(x.Element("Publisher"), String),
     CType(x.Element("ISBN"), String))
  End Function)
```

Comment: if i dont add ".Value" (like x.Element("Title").Value) i get an error like
"Value of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' cannot be converted to 'String'"

Comment: @AndroCoder use CType instead of DirectCast, will update

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've made my code like this and it's correct now

```
.Select(Function(x)
           Return New Book(
               DirectCast(x.Element("Title").Value, String),
               DirectCast(x.Element("Author").Value, String),
               DirectCast(x.Element("Publisher").Value, String),
               DirectCast(x.Element("ISBN").Value, String))
        End Function)
```

DirectCast and Value is important